# C: Check if array includes consecutive elements that are equal

Tags: c, arrays, type-conversion, c-strings, void-pointers

Yesterday I had a test on C where I coudn't figure out the last question:

We were given two arrays of two types of arrays: arrays including consecutive elements that are equal(eg: {"stack","heap","heap"}) and arrays of where no consecutive elements where equal (eg: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}).

We were then asked to find one function that returned 1 or 0 if the given array contained doubles or not. So this function had to work with both integer arrays and char * arrays.

This is what I came up with today (but it keeps giving the wrong answer and crashing afterwards or a segmentation fault when comparing the strings)

Edit: correct code (thanks to @BLUEPIXY !)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int contains_dup(void *array, size_t size, size_t sizeoftype, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*)){
    //array != NULL, size != 0
    char *obj = array;
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < size-1; ++i){
        if(cmp(obj + sizeoftype * i, obj + sizeoftype * (i+1)))
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int eqi(const void *a, const void *b){
    int x = *(const int *)a;
    int y = *(const int *)b;
    return x == y;
}
int eqs(const void *a, const void *b){
    return strcmp(a, b) == 0;
}

#define TEST(name, cmp)\
do{\
    int test;\
    puts(#name ":");\
    test = contains_dup(name, sizeof(name)/sizeof(*name), sizeof(*name), cmp);\
    test ? puts("doubles? Yes\n") : puts("doubles? No\n");\
}while(0)\
/**/

int main(void){
int ints_yes[] = {0,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5};
int ints_no[]  = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
char *strings_yes[]={"heap","stack","stack","overflow"};
char *strings_no[] ={"heap","stack","heap","stack","overflow"};

puts("test:");
TEST(ints_yes, eqi);
TEST(ints_no, eqi);
TEST(strings_yes, eqs);
TEST(strings_no, eqs);
return 0;
}
```

Wrong old code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int array_contains_doubles(void ** array, int size, int sizeoftype){
 int i;
 char **out =(char**) malloc(size * sizeof(char*));

 for(i=0;i<size;i++){            //trying to convert the array of ints to an 
    out[i] = array+i*sizeoftype; //array of char * eg: {1,2} ->{"1","2"}
//  *out[i] +='a';
    printf("%c\n",*out[i]);

 }
 out[i]= NULL;

 while(*(out+1)!=NULL){ 
    if(strcmp(*out,*(out++))==0){ //<- where i get the segmentation error
            return 1;
    }

 }

 return 0;

 }


int main(void){
  int i;
  int ints_yes[] = {0,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5};
  int ints_no[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
  char * strings_yes[]={"heap","stack","stack","overflow"};
  char * strings_no[]={"heap","stack","heap","stack","overflow"};

  int test = array_contains_doubles((void **) ints_no, 
  sizeof(ints_no)/sizeof(ints_no[0]), sizeof(int));

  (test) ? (printf("doubles? Yes")) : (printf("doubles? No"));

}
```

Sorry for any spelling mistakes, english is not my native language.

Comment: You are confusing arrays with pointers. `array_contains_doubles` expects a pointer to `void *`, but `ints_no` is automatically converted to `&ints_no[0]` which is a pointer to `int`. The `(void **)` cast hides the error.

Comment: `ints_no` isn't double pointer.

Comment: I suggest changing `array_contains_doubles` to use a `void *` argument instead of a `void **` argument, since a `void *` can point to any object regardless of its type.

Comment: To compare two objects you need to know their type(s) and to perform a type-appropriate comparison.  The only way a single function can do this for multiple different types is if you pass it an argument that allows it to determine what kind of comparison to perform.  The standard [`qsort()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) function is a canonical example of such a thing -- note how one of its arguments is a pointer to a type-appropriate comparison function.

Comment: Isn't `if(strcmp(*out,*(out++))==0)` UB? I think you should replace it with `if(strcmp(*out,*(out+1))==0)`

Comment: It's a bad idea to have the same function for two fundamentally different things. How could you know if the elements of the array are pointers to strings or doubles? You cannot even relay on `sizeoftype` because depending on your platform they could be the same for `char*` and for `double`. John Bollingers comment applys here.

Comment: Look at how `qsort` is done. You need a comparator function that takes a pointer to 2 elements.

Comment: ... and calling `malloc` (and no `free` btw) also kills performance.

Comment: @IanAbbott So could it work if i changed the arguments etc to void *? Could it work using void ** but with &ints_no ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz The problem is the test specified this had to be done using one function and one function only... The malloc part i forgot to delete (I first tried converting the array in a seperate function but then copied that code into this function)

Comment: @AdamT. Your going the wrong way. Look how `qsort` is done. There is no other way. There is no way to know if your `void*` points to an array of `doubles` or to an array of pointers to `char*`. You need a way to tell the `array_contains_doubles` function what type of data it is supposed to operate on.

Comment: @MichaelWalz That's what I thought too, on the test I ended up adding a parameter "char * type" and then in my function I chose what to do with the array after checking if the type given was "int" or "string". But that seemed way to sloppy (and we get marked down a lot for innefficient code).

Comment: @AdamT. you should'nt have added `char*` parameter but an `int` parameter, 0 meaning "string", 1 meaning "double", for example.

Comment: @AdamT If you are limited to a single function, you'll have to pass a parameter that tells it what type to use and use a `switch` statement with different `case` labels for the different types. E.g. define an enumeration type `enum type_code { type_int, type_str };` Pass a parameter of this type to the function, e.g. `enum type_code code`. Switch on this, e.g. `switch (code) { case type_int: ...; break; case type_str: ...; break; }`. Since you know the type, you don't need to pass the size of the type to the function, only the array length.

Comment: @MichaelWalz In the end the functionality is the same no? (of course char* is wasted memory and strcmp is more expensive than comapring two ints)

Comment: @AdamT.yes of course functionality is the same, but youv'e obviously understood my point. in real world doing a `strcmp` for such a thing is an absolute no go.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I get that, it just seemed like the wrong solution at the time (specifically because the teacher stressed the importance of one particular exercise in class where we used void points etc to perform a function that accepted multiple types of arrays. Altough that took an extra parameter specifying the function it had to use but I was blinded by the "only one function" on the test)

Comment: @MichaelWalz Anyways, thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: BTW `strings_no`  has duplicate elements.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes butt I need to check if the array contained two equal /consecutive/ elements.

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/o9qG5T)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks! Edit: your code checks for duplicates not only consecutive duplicates, i added the right code in the main post.

Comment: @AdamT. Ah, it is a constraint that it is continuous. I see. I updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your teacher is likely fishing for, is for you to implement a "functor" similar to the function pointer passed to `bsearch` (study this function). Something along the lines of this:

```
typedef int comp_func_t (const void*, const void*);

bool equal (const void* obj1, const void* obj2, comp_func_t* comp)
{
  return comp(obj1, obj2)==0;
}
```

You call `equal` from your application with a pointer to the objects to compare, no matter what kind of objects they are. The function pointer specifies how objects of this type should be compared. You then implement the comparison functions for each type:

```
int comp_int (const void* obj1, const void* obj2)
{
  int a = *(const int*)obj1;
  int b = *(const int*)obj2;

  if(a < b)
  {
    return -1;
  }
  else if(a > b)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else // a == b
  {
    return 0;
  }
}

int comp_str (const void* obj1, const void* obj2)
{
  ...
}
```

Typical use could be:

```
int x;
int y;
...
if(equal(&x, &y, comp_int))
{
  ...
}
```

Now this only compares two objects, so you'll have to expand this for an array by 1) sorting the array and 2) calling it for every two adjacent items in the sorted array, to find out if any are equal.

The above is the old, "de facto standard" way to implement type-specific behavior in C. In newer versions of the language, more elegant ways are available through the `_Generic` keyword, but this would probably not be addressed on a beginner-level class.

Comment: Thanks, i figured it was something like that but in the end I didn't dare to write a separate function as the question specified only using one function (which I probably misinterpreted, in hindsight they probably just meant that we coudnt write two function "int check_array_of_ints" and "int check_array_of_strings").

Comment: The array should be left unsorted in this case, since the problem is to check for _consecutive_ duplicates, not _any_ duplicates.